# нужно отчистить файл,и записать в него данные

Tags: java, файлы

вот код

```
if(content.contains("1223994251")) {
    writer.write(""); // очищаем, перезаписав поверх пустую строку
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    FileWriter writer2;
    writer2 = new FileWriter(file);
    writer2.write(content);
    writer2.flush();
    writer2.close();

} else {
    writer.write(""); // очищаем, перезаписав поверх пустую строку
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    FileWriter writer2;
    writer2 = new FileWriter(file);
    writer2.write("1223994251\r\n"+content); 
    writer2.flush();
    writer2.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете java8, то советую посмотреть в сторону класса Files, который содержит статические методы для работы с файлами.

В вашем случае хорошо подходит метод write, т.к. он автоматически перезаписывает содержащиеся данные в файле:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("путь/к/файлу"), "строка".getBytes())
```

Если вы захотите чтобы он дописывал данные, то нужно использовать дополнительный атрибут:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("путь/к/файлу"), "строка".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
```

UPD:

Цитата из [официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) к классу: "By default the method creates a new file or overwrites an existing file", что в переводе на русский значит что метод либо создает файл если его нет, либо перезаписывает его. Убедитесь что вы используете метод write БЕЗ третьего параметра, то есть передаете ему только путь к файлу и массив байтов из нужной строки.

Comment: а как мне сразу несколько строк перезаписать+ у меня переменная, с данными, а ваш способ не подходит, тюк там только текст, без переменных

Comment: Вы написали "Очистить файл и записать в него данные", если вам нужно менять только несколько строчек в файле, но при этом чтобы остальные оставались такими же, то вам нужно либо менять динамически, либо вычитывать весь файл, менять строку и записывать заново.

Что вам мешает создать отдельную строку в которую сохранить результат всех действий с вашими переменными и строками.[ "Строка".getBytes() ] ничем не отличается от [ String str = "Строка"; str.getBytes(); ]

Comment: мне нужно каждый раз отчищать текстовый файл и записывать в него новые данные

Comment: очищать- это значит удалить весь текст оттуда, чтобы он стал пустым

Comment: Мой код, верхняя строчка, делает то что вам нужно

Comment: а как туда вставить переменную с текстом, туда только такие разрешает "dadad"

Comment: а все, я нашел , это у меня баг был, сорри)

Comment: я вставил ваш код, верхний, он так же добавляет, мне ничего не перезаписал

Comment: Добавил ссылку на JavaDoc в которой гласит как работает метод. Убедитесь что вы используете именно нужный метод с нужными параметрами.